gprbuild not binding GNATCOLL SQL program
I'm trying to get started with SQLite database programming in Ada, and gprbuild is failing to compile my program.
The output from gprbuild:
using project file database_test2.gpr
Bind
   [gprbind]      database_test2.bexch
   [Ada]          database_test2.ali
error: "gnatcoll-sql-exec.adb" must be compiled
error: ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ada/adalib/gnatcoll_sql/gnatcoll-sql-exec.ali" is obsolete and read-only)
error: "gnatcoll-sql-exec-tasking.adb" must be compiled
error: ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ada/adalib/gnatcoll_sql/gnatcoll-sql-exec-tasking.ali" is obsolete and read-only)
error: "gnatcoll-sql-sqlite.adb" must be compiled
error: ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ada/adalib/gnatcoll_sqlite/gnatcoll-sql-sqlite.ali" is obsolete and read-only)
gprbind: invocation of gnatbind failed
gprbuild: unable to bind database_test2.adb

I tried linking to the files in my project folder, but that just led to another error message saying that a file cannot belong to several projects. I considered changing permissions of the /adainclude/ folder, but that doesn't seem like the way that this is meant to work.
I'm on Linux Mint 21.1, and all Ada-related packages were installed through the package manager.

I still don't know what the problem is, but I was able to get around it by using the -t binder flag.
